# Try to setup static IP on CentOS

Tags: linux, networking, bash, vim, centos-8

I am very new to Linux based operating systems. I can navigate terminal a little, I know how to "VIM".

I am trying to give my machine a static IP.
I need to get into and save an edited file to `/etc/sysconfig/network` but I cannot travel there for lack of better words.

I tried:
`/run/user/1000/gvfs/`
to
`bash: cd: /run/user/1000/gvfs/: No such file or directory`

Why?

Side note: I created the VIM /etc/sysconfig/network (I assume that's the name)

Command: `VIM /etc/sysconfig/network`

And idk where it went. I saved it by `:wq` before leaving VIM

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Thomas

P.S. my apologies on the formatting. I am pretty new to Stack Exchange as well.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the following how-to: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-centos-7-rhel-7-fedora-26.html

short version is:

1. be root
2. `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` (or how the NIC is called on your system)
3. file should look like so:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
# Static IP Address #
BOOTPROTO=none
# Server IP #
IPADDR=192.168.1.10
# Netmask #
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
# Default Gateway IP #
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
# DNS Servers #
DNS1=192.168.1.1
DNS2=8.8.8.8
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
# Disable ipv6 #
IPV6INIT=no
# Device Name #
NAME=enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
# Optional – This is system specific and can be created using ‘uuidgen enp0s3’ #
UUID=02d4a47b-3dbe-4e0b-ae4b-841a8c58e807
# Activate on Boot #
ONBOOT=yes
```